Looking for a list of ATP-S db versions certified with OCI Gen2 and Gen3
Looking for ATP-S database versions (19c, 21c, 23ai, etc) certified with Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC).
cant find anything on oracle's site or on google thru partner sites. appreciate if somebody can share the certification matrix list.
